# Golang. Послать и принять cookie

Tags: vue.js, golang, cookie, fetch

Есть приложение на го, которое делает авторизацию и редиректит на фронтовую приложуху, кладя туда куку. Выглядит так

```
cooka := http.Cookie{Name: "user_id", Value: userr.Id}
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "localhost")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, DELETE, PUT, POST, OPTIONS")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, Cookie")
http.SetCookie(w, &cooka)
http.Redirect(w, r, "http://localhost:8080", http.StatusFound)
```

Фронт, написаный на вью, делает гет запрос в эту же приложуху на адрес `localhost:3000/getUserData`, который, по моей теории, должет вместе с запросом отправить и куку, которая будет прочитана гошным бэком, но почему-то не отправляет. Запрос валится с ошибкой `GET http://localhost:3000/getUserData net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` и в самом запросе куки нет. В го, естественно, кука не находится. При этом из постмана всё замечательно читается. Не могу понять, почему фронт не шлёт куку.
Уже 2 дня не могу разобраться, помогите!

Comment: Непонятно по какому адресу работает приведённый код

Comment: @AlexeyTen гошное приложение на локалхост3000, фронт на локалхост8080

Comment: Покажите как фронт ходит в бэк (js?)